# Setting open multiple solutions by Visual Studio when starting Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-studio

Every morning, I open my computer (Windows 10) then I open two instances of Visual Studio (one for GUI solution, other for Service solution) for coding reasons.

I wish it can be automatic. For example: Just press 'Start' button on computer and come back after 5 minutes and you will see two Visual Studio with two solutions appear front of you.

So, is there anyway to do that? (bashscript is a way to do this, isn't it?)

Comment: Can't understand the two instances. What do you mean by "GUI solution" and "Service solution"?

Comment: Take a look at [run-multiple-instances-with-one-click-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498911/run-multiple-instances-with-one-click-in-visual-studio)

Comment: the two instance mean you run 2 .exe Visual Studio so you have two program. @Biswapriyo

Comment: "Why not place two shortcuts, containing the executable name with required arguments and place them in the StartUp directory? perhaps at: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup " , Compo said. That is a idea from another stackoverflow user. Until now, I'm still searching to implement it

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

1. Right click on .sln file
2. Click on "Create shortcut"
3. A new shortcut will be created [image: Here is an image for this step]
4. Copy the shortcut and past it in **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup**
5. Do again for other **.sln files** to achive "Open multiple solutions by Visual Studio when starting Windows"